# stunnel problems on Ubuntu 14 and Linux Mint 17

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, stunnel

I installed stunnel4 from the program manager. When I try to run stunnel on either of Ubuntu 14 or Linux Mint 17, I get the message below. I have this working on CentOS6.5 and on MacOS X Mavericks. Not sure what to try next. Rebuilding openssl is a mess, if that is even the problem.

```
idf@idf-ZBOX-ID42-BE ~ $ sudo stunnel
Clients allowed=500
stunnel 4.53 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu platform
Compiled with OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
Running  with OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
Update OpenSSL shared libraries or rebuild stunnel
Threading:PTHREAD SSL:+ENGINE+OCSP Auth:LIBWRAP Sockets:POLL+IPv6
Reading configuration from descriptor 3
Compression not enabled
PRNG seeded successfully
Initializing inetd mode configuration
Section stunnel: SSL server needs a certificate
str_stats: 2 block(s), 10 data byte(s), 116 control byte(s)
idf@idf-ZBOX-ID42-BE ~ $
```

my conf file looks like this:

```
idf@idf-ZBOX-ID42-BE ~ $ more /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf 
;Example stunnel configuration file by Michal Trojnara 2002-2006
; Some options used here may not be adequate for your particular configuration

; Certificate/key is needed in server mode and optional in client mode
; The default certificate is provided only for testing and should not
; be used in a production environment
;cert = stunnel.pem
;key = stunnel.pem
cert = /home/idf/Downloads/cert.pem
key  = /home/idf/Downloads/key.pem
fips = no
libwrap=no
;
;Protocol version (all, SSLv2, SSLv3, TLSv1)
;sslVersion = all
sslVersion = all 
ciphers = ALL

;
; Some security enhancements for UNIX systems - comment them out on Win32
chroot = /var/run/stunnel4/
setuid = stunnel4 
setgid = stunnel4 
; PID is created inside the chroot jail
pid = /home/idf/stunnel.pid


; Some performance tunings
socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1
compression = zlib

; Workaround for Eudora bug
options = DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS

; Authentication stuff
;verify = 2
; Don't forget to c_rehash CApath
;CApath = certs
; It's often easier to use CAfile
;CAfile = cacerts.pem
; Don't forget to c_rehash CRLpath
;CRLpath = crls
; Alternatively you can use CRLfile
;CRLfile = crls.pem

; Some debugging stuff useful for troubleshooting
debug = 7
output = /var/log/stunnel/stunnel.log

; Use it for client mode
client = yes

; Service-level configuration

[xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxx]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:9099
connect= xx.xx.xx.xx:2506

; vim:ft=dosini
idf@idf-ZBOX-ID42-BE ~ $
```

If I uninstall the stunnel that is in the repository and replace it with this one:

```
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/amd64/stunnel4/3:5.01-3
```

I still get even if I disable compression. I don't understand why it is telling me about the "Service [stunnel]: SSL server needs a certificate" since I am trying to use it only in client mode. Also, the other end does not need a certificate.

```
idf@idf-ZBOX-ID42-BE ~/Downloads $ sudo stunnel
[ ] Clients allowed=500
[.] stunnel 5.01 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu platform
[.] Compiled/running with OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
[.] Threading:PTHREAD Sockets:POLL,IPv6 SSL:ENGINE,OCSP,FIPS Auth:LIBWRAP
[ ] errno: (*__errno_location ())
[.] Reading configuration from descriptor 3
[.] FIPS mode disabled
[ ] Compression disabled
[ ] PRNG seeded successfully
[ ] Initializing inetd mode configuration
[!] Service [stunnel]: SSL server needs a certificate
idf@idf-ZBOX-ID42-BE ~/Downloads $ ps ax | grep stunnel
```

Comment: If I run stunnel4 I get no errors without zlib compression.

Answer (score 1):

i just beat my way thru this the other day.

you want stunnel4_5.01-3_amd64.deb - you'll have to download that - not in the repos yet. i believe someone made it work with 4.53, but i didn't manage it.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/amd64/stunnel4/3:5.01-3

openssl 1.0.1f and libssl.1.0.0 and libssl.1.0.0:i386 1.0.1f (they're the current versions) are good. but note this from your start output:

Compiled with OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
Running  with OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

i think updating stunnel as described above will sort that for you.

and the other thing you need to do is turn off compression in your stunnel.conf - none of the different types of compression i tried currently work. hopefully, that's temporary.

regards,

hth

Comment: hth, thanks for the tip. See the clarification at the end of my post above that takes into account your suggestion.

Comment: Actually, I was trying to run stunnel, not stunnel4. This latter version seems to run without errors if I comment out compression=zlib but I might need compression!? Then what?

Answer (score 0):

(I'm the same guys as above user3694589 - finally bothered to create an account.)

FYI, I just subscribed myself to this related bug and marked it as affecting me on launchpad.net:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/stunnel4/+bug/1315844

You might want to add yourself as well. Several minutes later, I got this email:

---

Status changed to 'Confirmed' because the bug affects multiple users.

** Changed in: stunnel4 (Ubuntu)
       Status: New => Confirmed

-- You received this bug notification because you are subscribed to the bug report. https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1315844 Title: won't start with compression on